# Was Arthur Seldom based on a particular real-life mathematician?

Tags: character, the-oxford-murders

In the 2008 film *The Oxford Murders*, the late John Hurt plays Arthur Seldom, a renowned professor of mathematics and logic at the University of Oxford. The film also refers to the proof of "Bormat's last theorem" - an obvious reference to [Fermat's last theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) - which fixes the setting of the film at 1993.

Given this reference in the film to real-life mathematicians, I wonder **whether Seldom himself was based on any real-life figure**. Are there any hints towards this either in the film itself or its [source novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Oxford_Murders_(novel)), or statements to this effect by people involved in the making of either?

Answer (score 5):

It appears that it was not.

Arthur Seldom was not based on a particular real-life mathematician. It was just a character that writer picked it up from his previous work, *About Roderer*, and that also shares some traits of the same character in *About Roderer*.

From [an interview with writer Guillermo Martinez](http://guillermomartinezweb.blogspot.in/2010/12/entrevista-el-grillo.html) (this page is in Spanish and I translated it using Google. So I am posting English version. (Emphasis mine))

> **Eg:** When you project, you conceive a novel, think of the end and then look for the characters or they are looking for, call the author? Because Arthur Seldom, protagonist of Crimes imperceptible appears already - although only - in About Roderer ...
>
> **GM:** In general I think first of the end, but **already with the main lines of the plot the characters emerge with some of their "necessary" traits. And there are also the first links between them** ... In the case of imperceptible Crimes I decided to use what in About Roderer was only an available name, and incarnate him as the protagonist.